# I am trying to get the ip address of a locally hosted server in the network in react native

Tags: react-native, mdns, localserver

Raspberry pi is connected to wifi and it is hosting a django server like treeleafpi.local i can access the server with treeleafpi.local:8000 in the web browser but i want to call api from react native app .

I used react-native-zeroconf to scan and i am able to get some ip address list like a printer but  i am unable to get the ip address of the django server ip .

---

when i used android app .local finder i got ip address from hostname like treeleafpi.local

**
Is there a way to get an ip address in react native  ?**